# JSQMessaging & Group Chat

Tags: ios, objective-c, message, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Does anyone know of any tutorials based using JSQMessage & Parse, but for group chats? I have a project I am currently working on that uses JSQMessage, but on one on one. I am still new to iOS and cannot find any tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. this is very easy to use you only need to format your sender,receiver messages.you can use image,and video also.

https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/SOMessaging

Comment: this is similar to JSQMessaging, but it doesnt show I can do group chats... do you know how I could go about doing so?

Comment: You can use sqlite to save message so you can populate from local storage.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this project that uses Parse and JSQMessagesViewController:

https://github.com/relatedcode/NotificationChat